# How to debug HTTP request?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, http, debugging, web

I am new to web services. In my application a random http request is getting generated and that request is failing (on chrome console I saw that its failing). I want to debug from where that request is getting generated. I thought of writing angularjs http interceptors to print the stack. Can someone guide me to debug this? Is there any way to know print the stack?

Comment: How is it failing? Whats the console output?

Comment: The generated request is  as follows :  https://localhost:9000/%7B%7B' I am getting 404 - Not found error.

Comment: If you're using chrome console, you might as well just hit the 'sources' tab in the developer tools window and open up the js file where you're making the request.
Put a break point in there and debug it in the dev tools window.